# DX - List of Bundle/Prefix types?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, force-cli, cli

With the DX CLI you can't deploy certain individual files - ex. aura and lightning components. You have to use syntax like

`sfdx force:source:deploy -m AuraDefinitionBundle:<aura bundle name>,ApexClass:<some class name>` and so on.

Is there any definitive list of all possible types of 'prefixes' like `AuraDefinitionBundle:` in SFDC docs? I've not yet come across one on https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference.htm

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the types in the [Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm) documentation. There is mostly a 1:1 relationship to those metadata types for the force:source:retrieve command. Settings are kind of an exception (e.g. Address Settings would be retrieved using `Settings:Address`), but I think that's the only one.

Edit: Updated Link. The types are located in the left nav menu.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox, exactly what I was looking for!